# Dynamic load from sql and then dynamic save

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a password protected weboage (internal company admin use only) that loads a row from sql using js, ajax and php. The webpage then displays the sql row but it also gets and displays the column names as these change over time.  The user can then amend the values with the idea to save the amended row back to the sql.

What would be the best way to insert the data back again as normally I would use the column names in the sql insert but in this scenario the php script doesn't know what the column names are so it won't know where to put them. I could try and just write the row in the correct order (without column names) but worry it would get out of sequence and write to the wrong column.  Can I somehow pass to the insert php script an array of the column names (maybe from the form label names) and values so that I can insert it dynamically to the correct columns?  I don't know how to get this from the html form when I press submit as I only get the values and no indictaion which column they belong to.

Comment: Set input names to column names and then use keys from `$_POST` to identify them?

Comment: Yes that seems to work, thank you.  The only tiny issue is that the Submit button is included in the list of posts so I manually exclude that.  I assume there's no way of ensuring the only posts I use are the form fields?

Comment: You need the submit, so the only remaining solution is to manually remove it. A bit of a dirty solution, but not that big a deal.